# How is it possible to receive 2 pulses from only 1 sent pulse?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, applied-physics

If we have a sample of a certain material to characterize it The sample is a cube with side length (L=1m). You used an ultrasonic (US) transducer to send an US pulse of frequency (f=5MHz) at normal incidence, and receive it at the other end of the sample. Assuming that the incident wave is composed of both shear and lateral waves.

Why would I receive here 2 pulses at the receiver at the other end of the sample although the transducer sent only one pulse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In solids sound can propagate as a longitudinal wave or as a shear wave and these two waves have different velocities. [The speed of a longitudinal wave is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound#Speed_of_sound_in_solids):

$$ v_p = \sqrt{\frac{K + \tfrac{4}{3}G}{\rho}} $$

and the speed of a shear wave is:

$$ v_s = \sqrt{\frac{G}{\rho}} $$

where $K$ is the bulk modulus and $G$ is the shear modulus. The longitudinal wave travels faster than the shear wave so from the original pulse you receive the longitudinal wave first then your receive the shear wave later. That's why you receive two pulses.

Answer (score 0):

@JohnRennie 's answer is interesting, but OP says that the ultrasound pulse is sent at "normal incidence". This implies that the ultrasound first travels in air and, therefore, is initially a longitudinal wave. My understanding is [there is no conversion of longitudinal wave to transverse wave at normal incidence](https://www.nde-ed.org/Physics/Waves/modeconversion.xhtml). I am not sure though this is true for anisotropic media as well.

Another possible explanation can be that the second pulse is produced after two reflections inside the cube (initially from the "rear" wall and then from the "front" wall).